# Insertion of a node to a BALANCED binary search tree

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

Suppose I have a binary balanced search tree and I get a stream of new nodes to insert to the tree, do you know an insertion algorithm that can guarantee that the tree will stay balanced after the insertion of the new nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AVL Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) is a self-balancing binary search tree. Following are two resources for the implementation:

1) [Resource 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/avl_tree_algorithm.htm)

2) [Resource 2](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/)